# Explanation on why ternary statement is not working like expected in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ternary-operator

Assuming `this.health() //returns 'default'`, why does

```
<div className="guage">

    // Why do these work as intended

    <div className={"guage-segment default " + (this.health() === 'default' ? 'active' : '')}>Default</div>
    <div className={"guage-segment danger " + (this.health() === 'danger' ? 'active' : '')}>Danger</div>

   // When I feel like this is the proper ternary syntax

    <div className={"guage-segment ok " + (this.health() === "ok") ? "active" : ""}>Ok</div>
    <div className={"guage-segment good " + (this.health() === "good") ? "active" : ""}>Good</div>

</div>
```

The first two `guage-segement` add the active class only when the condition is true, however the next 2 return active no matter what. I thought ternary syntax was `(condition) ? true : false` but it seems that `(condition ? true : false)` is what is working. Any explanation would be great.

Comment: tl;dr binary operator `+` has higher precedence than `?`

Answer (score 4):

() works because of Order of Operation.  () is the highest, if you remove () then addition will go first from left to right.

Here is MDN list of precedence from highest to lowest:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence